# Override Telerik Close Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, styles

I have a telerik close button on a dock that I am wanting to override the style of to allow the user to make a choice of what they want to close.

Take Notepad++ for example.. There is a "Close" and a "Close all BUT this" option.

That is exactly what I am wanting to do with this telerik radDock close button.

I have researched this and could not find anything helpful enough to really get me started. I just started using WPF (and really C#) so any helpful advice, code, or sample projects would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

Metro Smurf, it is pretty much exactly like the tutorial at this point. I am pretty new to WPF and C# so please be nice haha.

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="RadDockCloseButton1.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking"
                Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContextMenuTemplate">
        <telerik:RadContextMenu InheritDataContext="False">
            <telerik:RadMenuItem
                IsChecked="{Binding IsFloatingOnly}"
                Command="telerik:RadDockingCommands.Floating"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                CommandTarget="{Binding}"
                Header="{Binding Command.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>

            <telerik:RadMenuItem
                IsChecked="{Binding IsDockableOptionChecked}"
                Command="telerik:RadDockingCommands.Dockable"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                CommandTarget="{Binding}"
                Header="{Binding Command.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

            <telerik:RadMenuItem
                Command="local:RadDockingCommands.CloseAllButThisCommand"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                CommandTarget="{Binding}"
                Header="{Binding Command.Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />

        </telerik:RadContextMenu>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="telerik:RadPane">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenuTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenuTemplate}" />
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <telerik:RadDocking x:Name="radDocking">
        <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer>
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup x:Name="radPaneGroup">
                    <telerik:RadPane TitleTemplate="{StaticResource ContextMenuTemplate}" Title="Pane 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="Some simple text here"/>
                    </telerik:RadPane>
                </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
    </telerik:RadDocking>

</Grid>

</Window>
```

Here is my C#:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace RadDockCloseButton1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static class RadDockingCommands
        {
            private static RoutedUICommand closeAllPanesButThisCommand;

            public static RoutedUICommand CloseAllPanesButThisCommand
            {
                get
                {
                    if (closeAllPanesButThisCommand == null)
                    {
                        closeAllPanesButThisCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Close all panes but this", "CloseAllPanesButThisCommand", typeof(RadDockingCommands));
                    }

                    return closeAllPanesButThisCommand;
                }
            }

            public static void OnCloseAllPanesButThis(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                var pane = e.Parameter as RadPane;
                if (pane != null)
                {
                    var paneGroup = pane.PaneGroup;
                    if (paneGroup != null)
                    {
                        var panesToClose = paneGroup.EnumeratePanes().Where(x => !x.IsHidden && x.IsPinned);
                        foreach (var paneToClose in panesToClose)
                        {
                            if (paneToClose != pane)
                            {
                                paneToClose.IsHidden = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public static void OnCloseAllPanesButThisCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                e.CanExecute = false;
                var paneGroup = sender as RadPaneGroup;
                if (paneGroup != null)
                {
                    int childrenCount = paneGroup.EnumeratePanes().Count(x => !x.IsHidden && x.IsPinned);

                    if (childrenCount > 1)
                    {
                        e.CanExecute = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.CanExecute = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds more like you are wanting to add a context menu to the docking tab, re: that's how Notepad++ works. Or are you wanting to add 2 'close' buttons?

Comment: Yeah that sounds right. I would just rather it be a clickable tooltip instead of a right click then choose method of doing it. Do you know anything about adding a context menu to the radDock close button?

Comment: You could use this [Telerik How To Disable (hide) the Close Button](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddocking-how-to-disable-the-close-button.html). And then use the [Telerik How To Add Buttons the Header](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddocking-how-to-add-buttons-to-the-pane-headers.html). Or use the [Telerik How To Add Menu Items to RadPane](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddocking-how-to-add-menu-items-to-the-radpanes-menu.html). I've used each of them for similar scenarios. If you can post a clearer description of what you are trying to achieve, I may have some more concrete ideas.

Comment: I actually found that last link you sent me this morning. That is basically exactly what I am trying to do. However, I cannot get it to recognize RoutedUICommand. Is that because I am using WPF instead of Silverlight? Thank you so much for your help by the way. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The How To is specific to WPF. All the XAML and code behind needed for the commanding is right in the tutorial. If you're still running into issues, post your XAML and code.

Comment: Alright. You should be able to see my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm adding a second answer with a full and complete code sample. Note that the entirety of this sample was directly taken from the [Telerik How to Customize or Remove the RadPane's Menu](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/raddocking-how-to-add-menu-items-to-the-radpanes-menu.html). I've only put the pieces together from the various snippets. In other words, this is an OOB implementation from the Telerik tutorial.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="so.Tel.RadPaneCloseAll.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:so.Tel.RadPaneCloseAll"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ContextMenuTemplate">
            <telerik:RadContextMenu InheritDataContext="False">
                <telerik:RadMenuItem Command="telerik:RadDockingCommands.Floating"
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                     CommandTarget="{Binding}"
                                     Header="{Binding Command.Text,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                     IsChecked="{Binding IsFloatingOnly}" />

                <telerik:RadMenuItem Command="telerik:RadDockingCommands.Dockable"
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                     CommandTarget="{Binding}"
                                     Header="{Binding Command.Text,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                     IsChecked="{Binding IsDockableOptionChecked}" />

                <telerik:RadMenuItem Command="local:RadDockingCommands.CloseAllPanesButThisCommand"
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                     CommandTarget="{Binding}"
                                     Header="{Binding Command.Text,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            </telerik:RadContextMenu>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadPane">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenuTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenuTemplate}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <telerik:RadDocking>
            <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
                <telerik:RadSplitContainer>
                    <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                        <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 1" />
                        <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 2" />
                        <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 3" />
                        <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 4" />
                        <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 5" />
                    </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
            </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
        </telerik:RadDocking>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;

namespace so.Tel.RadPaneCloseAll
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
                typeof( RadPaneGroup ),
                new CommandBinding(
                        RadDockingCommands.CloseAllPanesButThisCommand,
                        RadDockingCommands.OnCloseAllPanesButThis,
                        RadDockingCommands.OnCloseAllPanesButThisCanExecute ) );
        }
    }

    public static class RadDockingCommands
    {
        private static RoutedUICommand closeAllPanesButThisCommand;

        public static RoutedUICommand CloseAllPanesButThisCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if( closeAllPanesButThisCommand == null )
                {
                    closeAllPanesButThisCommand = new RoutedUICommand( "Close all panes but this",
                                                                       "CloseAllPanesButThisCommand",
                                                                       typeof( RadDockingCommands ) );
                }
                return closeAllPanesButThisCommand;
            }
        }

        public static void OnCloseAllPanesButThis( object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            var pane = e.Parameter as RadPane;
            if( pane != null )
            {
                var paneGroup = pane.PaneGroup;
                if( paneGroup != null )
                {
                    var panesToClose = paneGroup.EnumeratePanes().Where( x => !x.IsHidden && x.IsPinned );
                    foreach( var paneToClose in panesToClose )
                    {
                        if( paneToClose != pane )
                        {
                            paneToClose.IsHidden = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static void OnCloseAllPanesButThisCanExecute( object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            e.CanExecute = false;
            var paneGroup = sender as RadPaneGroup;
            if( paneGroup != null )
            {
                int childrenCount = paneGroup.EnumeratePanes().Count( x => !x.IsHidden && x.IsPinned );

                if( childrenCount > 1 )
                {
                    e.CanExecute = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.CanExecute = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally! I actually was wanting that menu to pop up when I right clicked on the [x] button, but this will help me get to that point. Thanks again for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you're almost there.

```
<Window x:Class="RadDockCloseButton1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Docking"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

Should be (notice the `local` namespace):

```
<Window x:Class="RadDockCloseButton1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadDockCloseButton1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

The `local` namespace is referring to which class has the custom commmand. In this case, you've added the class to your `RadDockCloseButton1` namespace.

Register the command in your constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
    typeof( RadPaneGroup ),
    new CommandBinding(
        RadDockingCommands.CloseAllPanesButThisCommand,
        RadDockingCommands.OnCloseAllPanesButThis,
        RadDockingCommands.OnCloseAllPanesButThisCanExecute ) );
}
```

And move the `public static class RadDockingCommands` class so that it is not nested inside of the `MainWindow`. i.e.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
                typeof( RadPaneGroup ),
                new CommandBinding(
                        RadDockingCommands.CloseAllPanesButThisCommand,
                        RadDockingCommands.OnCloseAllPanesButThis,
                        RadDockingCommands.OnCloseAllPanesButThisCanExecute ) );
    }
}

public static class RadDockingCommands
{
    private static RoutedUICommand closeAllPanesButThisCommand;

    // etc...
}
```

Finally, test with several panes. Either add additional panes to your sample, or just use this:

```
<telerik:RadDocking>
    <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
        <telerik:RadSplitContainer>
            <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 1" />
                <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 2" />
                <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 3" />
                <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 4" />
                <telerik:RadPane Header="Pane 5" />
            </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
        </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
    </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
</telerik:RadDocking>
```

If this still isn't working for you, I'll post the entire working sample.

Comment: Yeah... It is still acting like RoutedUICommand is not a thing... I cannot thank you enough for all of your help...